# HTML toggle colors in elements with every element going through the same colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider this code:

```
var counter = 0;
function changeColor(elem) {

  var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Cyan"];
  elem.style.color = colors[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter === colors.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

I want to make elements which will go through the array of colors, changing everytime per click. The script works, but when I click an element 2 times, and then jump to another element and click there, it will resume the 3rd color instead of going back to the first one. I know that it's because of the global counter variable, but placing it into the function causes it to reset and thus making the colors only change to "red".

I'm not sure how to tackle the problem, Im also using a `this` context for the elements in HTML:

```
 <div>
      <p onclick="changeColor(this)">Hello</p>
      <p onclick="changeColor(this)">Bye</p>
      <p onclick="changeColor(this)">I love you!</p>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't quite understand the code. Could go into detail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `elem` is a DOM-node *(`<p>`-tag)* object, since it is an object you can set any property you wish like `counter`:

```js
function changeColor(elem) {
  var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Cyan"];
  var lastIndex = colors.length - 1;

  if (elem.counter === undefined || elem.counter == lastIndex) {
    elem.counter = 0;
  }
  else {
    elem.counter++;
  }
  
  elem.style.color = colors[elem.counter];
};
```

```html
<div>
  <p onclick="changeColor(this)">Hello</p>
  <p onclick="changeColor(this)">Bye</p>
  <p onclick="changeColor(this)">I love you!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that elem.counter bothered me, now I understand. Nice explanation!